# How can I replace value in cells in dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have cells with values **'...'**, I wanna replace them on **'NaN'**. My dataframe called **energy**.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

file_name_energy = "data/Energy Indicators.xls"
energy = pd.read_excel(file_name_energy)
energy.replace('...', np.NaN)
```

I tried to use replace() but it doesn't work and dont output any error.

[energy.head(10)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09rAa.png)

Comment: Could you please copy paste the result of `print(energy.head(10)` to your question (there should be "..." in the data, otherwise we need parts of your df where there are "..." values)

Comment: @Rabinzel, I added screenshot

Comment: Some general information on how to ask here on SO. [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). For now try the given answer, it might solve your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reassign your dataframe or use `inplace=True`:

```
energy= energy.replace('...', np.NaN) #or energy.replace('...', np.NaN, inplace=True)
```

But since you're reading and Excel, why not using `na_values` parameter of [**`pandas.read_excel`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) ?

Try this :

```
energy = pd.read_excel(file_name_energy, na_values= ["..."])
```

From the documentation:

> **na_values** : scalar, str, list-like, or dict, default None
>
> > Additional strings to recognize as NA/NaN.
> > If dict passed, specific per-column NA
> > values. By default the following values are interpreted as NaN: ‘’,
> > ‘#N/A’, ‘#N/A N/A’, ‘#NA’, ‘-1.#IND’, ‘-1.#QNAN’, ‘-NaN’, ‘-nan’,
> > ‘1.#IND’, ‘1.#QNAN’, ‘’, ‘N/A’, ‘NA’, ‘NULL’, ‘NaN’, ‘n/a’, ‘nan’,
> > ‘null’.